# How to continue "on error" using Fastlane

Tags: automation, fastlane

I am trying to automate deployments into TestFlight using Fastlane.  I want it to continue "on error" even if one of the lanes errors out.

For example, if I run "doall" below and "item1" errors out, I want it to still run "item2" and "item3".

Is this possible, if so how?  Thanks!

```
lane :item1 do
 # Do some stuff
end

lane :item2 do
 # Do some stuff
end

lane :item3 do
 # Do some stuff
end

lane :doall do
 item1 # This causes an error
 item2
 item3
end

error do |lane, exception|
 # Send error notification
end
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use Ruby error handling to do that

```
lane :item1 do
 # Do some stuff
end

lane :item2 do
 # Do some stuff
end

lane :item3 do
 # Do some stuff
end

lane :doall do
 begin
   item1 # This causes an error
 rescue => ex
   UI.error(ex)
 end
 begin
   item2
 rescue => ex
   UI.error(ex)
 end
 begin
   item3
 rescue => ex
   UI.error(ex)
 end
end

error do |lane, exception|
 # Send error notification
end
```

It's not super beautiful, but that's the best way to do it, if you want to catch errors for each of the lanes.

Comment: @KrauseFx what is the swift equivalent for this. i.e how can I achieve it in fastfile.swift?

Comment: Looking for a `finally` block? Use `ensure`! The Ruby analog to try-catch-finally is begin-rescue-ensure

Answer (score 11):

Ruby

```
begin
  do_something_that_may_cause_error
rescue => ex
  # handle error
ensure
  # do something that always run like clean up
end
```

Swift

```
defer { 
  // do something that always run like clean up
}
do {
  try doSomethingThatMayCauseError()
} catch (error) {
  // handle error
}
```